# App rejection from apple account

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload an app on iTunes connect, but it got rejected with the below statement.

From Apple
4. 1 Design: Copycats
Guideline 4.1 - Design - Copycats

Your app or its metadata appears to contain misleading content. Specifically, your app includes content that resembles H2O Pools without the necessary authorization.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

Please demonstrate your relationship with any third-party brand owners represented in your app.

The attached screenshot is :-

[image]

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your app is branded a representing a business "H20 pools" then it needs to be submitted from a company developer registered by that company or you need to provide the authorisation to use the brand(s) shown in your app

Comment: How would i provide the authorization to use the brand shown in the app ?

Comment: I think you have to Upload app with Client Developer account. Because content in the pic may be related to another firm.

Comment: so what are the changes will be made in the app ?

Comment: I guess you would need some sort of legal letter from the brand/trademark holder or use a company developer account

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Do you have approval or authorization to use that content in your application?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing same problem in my app.
According to apple you, you use only that image which you have copy right, And in your App there are some products which are belong to some company. Then Apple want to some legal documents for these images.

For mor https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#copycats